# Can't write regexp

Tags: regex, perl

Hi I need to get to $submitkey a value mjxjezhmgrutgevclt0qtyayiholcdctuxbwb. What's wrong with my code?

```
my $str = '<input type="hidden" value="set" name="fr.posted"></input><input type="hidden" value="mjxjezhmgrutgevclt0qtyayiholcdctuxbwb" name="fr.submitKey"></input><div class="form-actions form-actions__centrate"><button value="clicked" id="hook_FormButton_button_accept_request" onclick="className +=" button-loading"" class="button-pro form-actions__yes" type="submit" name="button_accept_request"><span class="button-pro_tx">Войти</span>';
($submitkey) = $str =~ m/value="(.*?)" name="fr.submitKey"/;
print $submitkey;
```

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve, could you please clarify the question?

Comment: blast it all, I hate it when I prepare a full answer and then notice that the question was asked last year and someone made a tag-only edit which bumped it up. grrrrr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are matching from the first instance of `value` all the way until `"fr.submitKey"`.

Take advantage of the fact that every value is contained within quotes; only look for non-quote characters as part of the `value`.

Additionally, it is cleaner to use the special capturing-group variables:

```
my $str = '<input type="hidden" value="set" name="fr.posted"></input><input type="hidden" value="mjxjezhmgrutgevclt0qtyayiholcdctuxbwb" name="fr.submitKey"></input><div class="form-actions form-actions__centrate"><button value="clicked" id="hook_FormButton_button_accept_request" onclick="className +=" button-loading"" class="button-pro form-actions__yes" type="submit" name="button_accept_request"><span class="button-pro_tx">Войти</span>';
$str =~ m/value="([^"]*)" name="fr.submitKey"/;
$submitkey = $1;
print $submitkey;
```

Answer (score 2):

Never use `.*?`. It's never what you are actually trying to do. Even if you get it to work, it's far too likely to create extremely bad performance when there is no match. In this case, use `[^"]*`

Comment: Code that changes `.*?` to `[^"]*`? `perl -i -pe's/\.\*\?/\[\^"\]\*/g' yourscript.pl`

Comment: Do you really need to escape the RHS of the substitution? =)

Answer (score 1):

`.*?` does not cause Perl to search for the shortest possible match inside the whole string. Therefore the text before the `.*?` matches earlier in the string, and Perl is happy that it finds a match there. `.*?` simply means that it matches as few characters as possible from that first point where the part before `.*?` matches.

As @ikegami said: use `[^"]*` instead in your particular case.

Answer (score 0):

Much better to use a real DOM parser for this task. I like [Mojo::DOM](https://metacpan.org/module/Mojo%3a%3aDOM) which is part of the [Mojolicious](http://mojolicio.us) tool suite. Note that `use Mojo::Base -strict` enables `strict`, `warnings` and `utf8`. The `at` method finds the first instance which matches using CSS3 selectors.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use Mojo::Base -strict;
use Mojo::DOM;

my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new(<<'END');
<input type="hidden" value="set" name="fr.posted"></input><input type="hidden" value="mjxjezhmgrutgevclt0qtyayiholcdctuxbwb" name="fr.submitKey"></input><div class="form-actions form-actions__centrate"><button value="clicked" id="hook_FormButton_button_accept_request" onclick="className +=" button-loading"" class="button-pro form-actions__yes" type="submit" name="button_accept_request"><span class="button-pro_tx">Войти</span>
END

my $submit_key = $dom->at('[name="fr.submitKey"]')->{value};
say $submit_key;
```